# Unable to install remote charts using virtual helm repo in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I have created a Helm repository in Jfrog Artifactory using 'Quick Setup'.

Then used the Jfrog helm binary to add the virtual 'helm' repo:
[image]

I am able to add custom charts to the virtual repo, install them but not able to install charts from the helm-remote (i.e stable) repo:

[image]

When I try to access any such chart, helm throws as error:

[image]

On the Artifactory web ui, the helm virtual repo lists all the remote charts, but I'm unable to install them:

[image]

I have done "helm repo update" multiple times. And also have deleted ~/.helm folder and "init" again. Still, am plagued by the same problem.

I see the following error in the Artifactory System Logs repeated several times:

```
2018-02-28 09:18:34,266 [art-exec-2] [ERROR] (o.a.a.h.r.m.HelmVirtualMerger:194) - 
Couldn't read index file in remote repository helm-remote : 
(was com.github.zafarkhaja.semver.UnexpectedCharacterException) 
(through reference chain: org.jfrog.repomd.helm.model.HelmIndexYamlMetadata["entries"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["grafana"]->java.util.TreeSet[3])
```

[image]

What can be the possible issues here? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr -
This issue was fixed in Artifactory 5.9.0 - 
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15668

The problem is that Artifactory didn't support Helm charts with non-SemVer 2 in version 5.8, and only after version 5.8 came out a non SemVer2 was added to the stable chart repo. (grafana 0.6)
This issue was fixed in 5.9.0, and you should be able to resolve remote chart correctly.

check out Artifactory release notes - 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.9

Comment: Hey @DonMy thank you for your response. I upgraded the Artifactory version and now it's working